# SQLException stack trace

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat

So I got sort of strange situation. I have Spring webapp and in it I have JNDI datasource that I have defined in tomcat's server.xml to connect to mysql database
I have mysql-connector-java 5.1.2 in my Maven pom.

Application works when I start it from localhost, but when I deploy it to remote tomcat it is not getting the call to the database.

This Exception occurs :

```
Couldnt execute sql CALL shareholders_company_list(?)
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Unable to create correct SQLException class instance, error class/codes may be incorrect. Reason:

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

java.sql.SQLException
MESSAGE: Can't instantiate required class due to java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException

STACKTRACE:

java.sql.SQLException: Can't instantiate required class due to java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException
```

Is there away to avoid this ClassNotFoundException, so that I can get full stack trace, since it seems that explicit error why this happens is in MySQLNonTransientConnectionException, and I can't seem to reach it.

Comment: check the scope of the dependency, is it being bundled with the war that you are creating?

Comment: @Bilbo Baggins scope is not defined, so I guess <compile> as default

Comment: check is it being included in the war? It should be :)

Comment: @Bilbo Baggins Yes it is there in WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import required version(if you don't have any preference go for latest) of `mysql-connector-java-latestVersion.jar` under `tomcat\lib`

Comment: I'll try this as soon as possible... is it required to restart tomcat after I import jar to lib folder ?